# ArcCatalog Error Adding WMS Server

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wms, arcgis-10.2, arccatalog

When I tried to add a wms server in ArcCatalog, the following message came up: "The URL you passed in uses a protocol that is not supported." . The WMS Server is the following gis.ktimanet.gr/wms/wmsopen/wmsserver.aspx?. It's the Greek Cadastre WMS Server. I use ArcGis 10.2. Exactly the same message came up in QGIS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the Add WMS Server in Catalog window and then paste `http://gis.ktimanet.gr/wms/wmsopen/wmsserver.aspx?` with the http:// in the beginning. [image]